# Django Pillow error name has attr no defined, possible WSGI issue

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, python-imaging-library

I have no problems working with Pillow in my development environment - and have not had any issues with it either on a public server where I have implemented mod_wsgi.

However, today, when attempting to upload an image in the admin, I get this error message

```
File "/home/<username>/virtualenvs/<sampleenv>/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/PIL/Image.py", line 585, in __del__
NameError: name 'hasattr' is not defined
```

It must relate to mod_wsgi since this is the only difference between my development and production environment. Why this has suddenly happened is a mystery.

This is my /etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.load file:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module 
/home/<username>/virtualenvs/<sampleenv>/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/apache2/wsgi
WSGIPythonHome /home/<username>/virtualenvs/<sampleenv>
```

I have not attempted to copy the mod_wsgi module into the Apache installation - perhaps this is the problem but I'm not sure how to do this.

I hope I've managed to explain the problem clearly - any help would be great!

**UPDATE**

The problem was caused by the fact that the media folder was not writable by www-data. This has been fixed, and the issue has been resolved. There was no issue with the mod_wsgi configuration.

Comment: Is that virtual environment based off the system Python 3.6 installation, or is it based off Anaconda Python, or separate Python install? If you run ``mod_wsgi-express module-config``, does it output a ``LoadFile`` directive before the ``LoadModule`` directive? Ensure you are using the full output from ``mod_wsgi-express module-config`` in the Apache configuration file. The ``LoadFile`` line is important when using non system Python version.

Comment: Also, are you sure you see this error message when the WSGI request is being handled? Are you sure it isn't occurring when the process the WSGI application is running in is being shutdown? You can set ``LogLevel info`` in Apache to have mod_wsgi log more details about when process shutdown is occurring.

Comment: Hi Graham, in response to your first comment, the environment is based off the Python3.6 installation. However, rather than use the main Apache configuration I am using a module based in one of my virtual environments (which I know I must not delete). See code above. That's where the error is being generated from. That surprised me since the site in question has its own venv. Can you show me how to shut the process down and then start it again? Everything was working fine recently which makes this all the more puzzling!

Comment: Hi Graham, sorry I am struggling here. I am still able to use the sample site in question but I just don't understand why image uploading has suddenly stopped working. Am I able to place /mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so under /usr/lib/apache2/modules ? I have tried this but to no avail.

Comment: Hi, this is the output from mod_wsgi-express module-config - which I've used in /etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.load as described. I am not using the virtual environment of the site in question - rather a virtual env from site which won't be deleted. The docs suggested this was fine?
LoadModule wsgi_module "/home/<username>/virtualenvs/<sampleenv>/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
WSGIPythonHome "/home/<username>/virtualenvs/<sampleenv>"
Sorry Graham, the installation is therefore based on a separate env not the system (1st comment)

Comment: Hi, I've solved the issue - it wasn't a mod_wsgi problem. The media folder was not writable by www-data ... fixed that and the issue has been resolved. Graham - thank you for your assistance, much appreciated.

Comment: Commenting here as well in case it prevents some headaches: in multiple cases Apache throws such errors when in fact the underlying problem is something completely different. Try turning `DEBUG` on in your `settings.py`, and something else might turn up! (In my instance Apache was throwing the `hasattr` error when in reality all I did wrong was to pass an incorrect parameter to a template function in my Django app.)

Comment: Many thanks for getting back - will bear this in mind!